# Custom URL in Ember.Model in revision 11

Tags: ember.js

After I jumped from `rev 4` to `rev 11`, following code doesn't work anymore:

```
App.Coffee
    brand: DS.attr "string"

App.Coffee.reopenClass
    url: "different/location/coffee"
```

How can I set a custom url in `rev 11`?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No, but nothing seems to happen either... It builds the url like `localhost/coffees`,  while `rev 4` builds the url like `localhost/different/location/coffee`...

Comment: coffee(s) seems to me that some other part of your code is intercepting... Do you have more models? Could you provide more code samples?

Answer (score 0):

You do it on the store instead with `buildUrl`:

```
Store: DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 11,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
        buildURL: function(url) {
            return 'different/location/coffee/%@'.fmt(url);
        }
    })
})
```

(Used in conjunction with `pluralization` it will work wonders.)

Comment: The thing is, I have other models as well. `Model.CoffeeMachine` should use the normal `localhost/coffeemachines/1`. The thing I liked about `Model.reopenClass(url: "xy")` was that I could use different URLs for different models and kind of emulate the nested URL behaviour for my RESTful interface. Will `pluralization` do that for me?

Comment: You can implement a different adapter for your models, and then use the `buildURL` approach above. See "Multiple Adapters": http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-a-store/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by registering an adapter for the model:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
});

App.Store.registerAdapter('App.Coffee', DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'different/location'
}));
```